# Constrain MySQL column to be JSON object

Tags: mysql, json

I have a database with a JSON column called `notifications` which contains an object containing email addresses. For some reason, in some cases, the data was entered with the quotes escaped and in others, the quotes were not escaped. When the string is escaped, MySql interprets it as a STRING. When not escaped, it is an OBJECT

```
mysql> select notifications,json_type(notifications) from table group by notifications;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| notifications                                 | json_type(notifications) |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
| {"any": ["aaa@yyy.org", "bbb@yyy.org"]}       | OBJECT                   |
| NULL                                          | NULL                     |
| "{\"XFR\":[\"aaa@zzz.com\",\"bbb@zzz.com\"]}" | STRING                   |
| "{\"XFR\":[\"aaa@ccc.org\",\"bbb@ccc.org\"]}" | STRING                   |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Is there any way to put a constraint on MySql to restrict the column to JSON objects instead of strings or arrays?

EDIT: Trigger Option

I was hoping for more of a native MySQL approach, but this works:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER object_only BEFORE INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF json_type(NEW.jdoc) <> "OBJECT"
  THEN
   SIGNAL SQLSTATE '02000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Warning: JSON must be object';
  END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Basically I would work out which bit of code was causing the duff data to be stored and correct it. You cannot work with an unreliable data type. Then a quick query to correct the database and you are golden

Comment: It's probably user entry, which is why I need a programmatic means of preventing it. I had thought the MySQL would be able to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a MySQL column to be the `json` type, then MySQL will automatically validate every value which you attempt to insert or update in that column.  For example, the following snippet will fail, because the JSON is malformed (missing a closing `}` at the end of the object):

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1 (jdoc JSON);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"');
```

Realistically speaking, relying on a database-level failure to validate your JSON content is probably not the the best approach.  It would be better to validate your JSON in the application layer, before doing an insert/update in your MySQL table.

Comment: Right, but if I do `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('\"not json\"');` it will not throw an error.

Comment: @mankowitz A single string in double quotes is actually valid JSON.  Maybe you have some _other_ sort of validation in mind here.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was after. I want to constrain the column to be a json object. See trigger above.

Comment: @mankowitz `"not json"` _is_ a JSON object `:-)`

Comment: A scalar string is a valid JSON _value_, but it's not a JSON _object_.